# DAG Minimum Path Cover in O(nlogn)?

Tags: graphs, intervals

I asked this question on stackoverflow, but was suggested to post to same here. So here goes.

The following problem was asked in the recent [October 20-20 Hack on Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/oct13/challenges/missile-defend) :

> Evil Nation A is angry and plans to launch N guided-missiles at the
>   peaceful Nation B in an attempt to wipe out all of Nation B’s people.
>   Nation A’s missile i will arrive in nation B at the time ti. Missile i
>   communicates with its headquarters by unique radio signals with a
>   frequency equal to fi. Can you help the peaceful Nation B survive by
>   building a defensive system that will stop the missiles dead in the
>   sky?
>
> **Defensive system:**
>
> The only way to defend Nation B from the attacking missile is by
>   counter attacking them with a hackerX missile. You have a lot of
>   hackerX missiles and each one of them has its own radio frequency. An
>   individual hackerX missile can destroy Evil Nation A’s attacking
>   missile if the radio frequency of both of the missiles match. Each
>   hackerX missile can be used an indefinite number of times. Its
>   invincible and doesn’t get destroyed in the collision.
>
> The good news is you can adjust the frequency of the hackerX missile
>   to match the evil missiles’ frequency. When changing the hackerX
>   missile’s initial frequency fA to the new defending frequency fB, you
>   will need |fB - fA| units of time to do.
>
> If two evil missles with same
>   frequency arrive at the same time, we can destroy them both with one
>   hackerX missile. You can set the frequency of a hackerX missile to any
>   value when its fired.
>
> What is the minimum number of hackerX missiles you must launch to keep
>   Nation B safe?
>
> **Input Format:** The first line contains a single integer N denoting the
>   number of missiles.  This is followed by N lines each containing two
>   integers ti and fi denoting the time & frequency of the ith missile.
>
> **Output Format:** A single integer denoting the minimum number of
>   hackerX’s you need to defend the nation.
>
> **Constraints:** 
>   1 <= N <= 100000
>
> 0 <= ti <= 100000
>
> 0 <= fi <= 100000
>
> t1 <= t2 <= … <= tN

The problem gets reduced to a Minimum Path Cover Problem which is to be solved in `O(nlogn)` time based on the constrainsts.
However the best solution to a Minimum Path Cover Problem is using the Hopcroft–Karp algorithm, that leads to the Maximal Matching Problem. The solution to which is `O(n^2.5)`.
But the following solution by `icyrhyme9733` solves the problem in `O(nlogn)` :

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<pair<int, int> > vp;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int t, f;
        cin >> t >> f;
        vp.push_back(make_pair(t + f, t - f));
    }
    sort(vp.begin(), vp.end());
    reverse(vp.begin(), vp.end());
    vector<int> last(vp.size(), numeric_limits<int>::max());
    for(int i = 0; i < vp.size(); ++i) {
        *lower_bound(last.begin(), last.end(), vp[i].second) = vp[i].second;
    }
    cout << lower_bound(last.begin(), last.end(), numeric_limits<int>::max()) - last.begin() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is it solving a `Minimum Path Cover Problem in O(nlogn)` time ?  Or is there an optimization that I am missing ?

I found a similar problem on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508198/1016784). They have taken advantage of the fact that the graph is an Interval Graph. Even though being very similar, the same solution cannot be implemented, as the intervals are inverted.

Comment: I speak C++, and on a quick skim, the answer is yes. But I think the question itself is about understanding a specific program written in a specific programming language. Thus I think it is better suited for [SO]. (Otherwise, the question is asking us to verify the correctness of an implementation, and is not a good fit for this site).

Comment: note that OP mentions they started on SO, and got a comment to try here.  But there are actually 3 answers on the stack overflow copy of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639396/dag-minimum-path-cover-in-onlogn

Comment: I actually struck upon a much more elegant solution very recently. Completely forgot I had made a post about it here as well.